# Spring-Wicket: Bean Injection with Resource

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, wicket, wicket-1.6

I am writing tests for my wicket-application and need to inject a Spring Bean into a page (done by annotation) to do this.
Consider following code:

```
protected void setUp() {
  tester = new WicketTester();
  scanService = new ScanService();

  ApplicationContextMock appctx=new ApplicationContextMock();
  appctx.putBean("pxGenericService", new PxGenericServiceImpl());

  tester.getApplication().getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(tester.getApplication(), appctx));
}
```

This actually seem to work (no nullpointer). The problem is: the bean got a resource (variable with @Resource annotation) and when I run the test on the page, this resource turns out to be null (nullpointer exception). How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add an instance of all dependencies your bean has to the mock application context. So add an instance of the class `PxGenericServiceImpl` uses to `appctx`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `SpringComponentInjector` supports `@Resource`. The only supported annotations are `@SpringBean` and `@Inject`. See `AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory`:

```
@Override
public boolean supportsField(final Field field)
{
    return field.isAnnotationPresent(SpringBean.class) || field.isAnnotationPresent(Inject.class);
}
```